# Why can't I find the id?

Tags: javascript, json, selection, steroids

I am trying to change the text between the "h3" tags. New text should be moved from json-file. But the programm can not find the "h3"-element while the fields from the json-file are being read correctly. 
Here is a part of the json-file:

```
var teachers=JSON.parse( string_teachers );  
var i;
var T_name;
var Subject;
for (i=1; i<teachers.Teachers.length+1; i++) {
  T_name=teachers.Teachers[i-1].T_name;
   Subject=teachers.Teachers[i-1].Subject;
   var str="#"+i;
    $(str).find("h3").text(T_name);
 }
```

And a part of the html:

```
 <div class="grid" id="1">

     <img src="teachers/bobr.jpg">
     <h3 >Боброва Даша</h3>
     <p>Математический анализ</p>
</div>
<div class="divider">
<img src="views/divider.png" >
</div>
<div class="grid" id="2">
    <img src="teachers/korolev.jpg">
        <h3>Королев Даня</h3>
        <p>Программирование 1</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: The json is ok, I have checked in the online service

Comment: find is from jQuery not pure json are sure you have that library?

Comment: Are you sure this is your exact code. Because `(str).find("h3")` should throw a `undefined is not a function` or something similar, as `str` is a string, and a string does not have a function `find`.

Comment: Yes, I have already made some animation with jquery mobile and Ajax

Comment: [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) works currently only in FF, it's part of the ECMAScript proposal.

Comment: FF is an abbreviation of FireFox, but I'm afraid I was slightly wrong with this, since `str` seems to be a string, not an array. Probably afmeva's answer is correct, you've only forgotten to use `$`?

Comment: No, I haven't forgotten, that was just my incorrect paste of code.

Comment: As far as I understand find() should work here

Comment: The problev is that the programm can't find the html - element by id. For example, if I try alert($(str).find("h3").text()) the application gives empty messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks you are missing jQuery function. here:

```
 (str).find("h3").text(T_name);
```

Use it:

```
 $(str).find("h3").text(T_name);
```

I was missing some at JSON, yor issue is: DOM is no loaded yet when you are trying to access it

```
function foo() {

var string_teachers = '{"Teachers":[{"T_name":"value1", "Subject": "value2"},{"T_name":"value2",           "Subject": "value2"}]}'

var teachers = JSON.parse(string_teachers);
var i;
var T_name;
var Subject;
for (var i = 0; i < teachers.Teachers.length; i++) {
    T_name = teachers.Teachers[i].T_name;
    Subject = teachers.Teachers[i].Subject;
    var str = "#" + (i+1);
    console.log(str)
    $(str).find("h3").html(T_name);
}
}
$(document).ready(foo)
```

Comment: Good catch I just noticed this

Comment: Sorry, that was my incorrect paste of code. Of course, I had the function, so $ now does not solve the problem :-(

Comment: you are looping JSON wrong, JSON is not an array so it doesnt have .length property. I´ll edit my post adding some code

Comment: sorry, no result... Yes, json is the same practically

Comment: and now alert (T_name) in the cycle gives 'undefined'

Comment: you need a ready (on load window) function. rememeber, you always need waiting for DOM to access it

Comment: And why do you parse string_teacher not this one var string_teachers=JSON.stringify(teachers)?

Comment: You need an Object, not a String. Stringify = strings, JSON.parse =object

Comment: Thank you! But you parsed wrong object, (I think that we need a string to parse, not an object) I have fixed it and it works!)

Comment: buddy, I was parsing a string, not an object, so, yes! we need a string to parse. YW